# IOS Swift MQTT won't publish message to Raspberry Pi

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, raspberry-pi, mqtt

l am quite new to iOS development and just having a hard time trying to make MQTT publish messages from my phone. l wish to use the app I have built to control the raspberry pi wheels (the step motors more specifically). I made a button to connect to the robot.

```
struct ConnectToRobot: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            print("Connect to robot")
            mqttClient.connect()
            
        } label:  {
            Image(systemName: "circle")
                .renderingMode(.template)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
        }
    }
}
```

When l press the button from the app in my phone, it connects to the raspberry pi and it shows me the message "subscribing", "subscribed".  However, when l press any other buttons on the app, like "forward" or anything else it seems to not work at all. Here is the code from the RPi:

```
#For checking the connection status
def connectionStatus(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("subscribing")
    mqttClient.subscribe("robot/move")
    print("subscribed")




#movement control
def messageDecoder(client, userdata, msg):
    message = msg.payload.decode(encoding='UTF-8')
    
    if message == "f":
        forward()
        mess2 = msg.payload.decode(encoding='UTF-8')
        
        print("^^^ forward! ^^^")
        
    elif message == "b":
        backward()
        print("\/ backward \/")
        
    elif message == "l":
        left()
        print("<- left")
        
    elif message == "r":
        right()
        print("-> right")
        
    elif message == "fl":
        diagFL()
        print("\ Diagonal Front Left")
        
    elif message == "fr":
        diagFR()
        print("/ Diag Front Right")
        
    elif message == "bl":
        diagBL()
        print("/ Diag Back Left")
        
    elif message == "br":
        diagBR()
        print("\ Diag back Right")
        
    elif message == "cw":
        cw()
        print("O Clockwise")

    elif message == "ccw":
        ccw()
        print("O Counter Clockwise")
            
    elif message == "s":
        stop()
       
    else:
        print("?!? Unknown message?!?")


# Set up calling functions to mqttClient
mqttClient.on_connect = connectionStatus
mqttClient.on_message = messageDecoder


# Connect to the MQTT server & loop forever.
# CTRL-C will stop the program from running.
mqttClient.connect(serverAddress)
mqttClient.loop_forever()
```

This is my swiftUI code below:

```
import SwiftUI
import CocoaMQTT





let mqttClient = CocoaMQTT(clientID: "Robot", host: "raspberrypi.local", port: 1883)


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack{
                HStack {
                    VStack {
                        BackwardLeft()
                        Backward()
                        BackwardRight()
                    }
                    VStack{
                        Left()
                        ConnectToRobot()
                        Right()
                    }
                    VStack {
                        ForwardLeft()
                        Forward()
                        ForwardRight()
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


//First VStack
//Back left
struct BackwardLeft: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            print("Move back left")
        } label:  {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.up.left.square")
                .renderingMode(.template)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
        }
    }
}


//Backward
struct Backward: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button (action: {
        
            mqttClient.publish("robot/move", withString: "b")
            print("Move back")
        }, label:  {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.left.square")
                .renderingMode(.template)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
        })
    }
}


//Back Right
struct BackwardRight: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            print("Back right")
            
        } label:  {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.down.left.square")
                .renderingMode(.template)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
        }
    }
}


//Second VStack
//Left
struct Left: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            mqttClient.allowUntrustCACertificate = true
            mqttClient.publish("robot/move", withString: "l")
            print("Move left")
        } label:  {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.up.square")
                .renderingMode(.template)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
        }
    }
}

//MQTT Connection
struct ConnectToRobot: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            print("Connect to robot")
            mqttClient.connect()
            
        } label:  {
            Image(systemName: "circle")
                .renderingMode(.template)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
        }
    }
}

//Right
struct Right: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            print("Move right")
            mqttClient.publish("robot/move", withString: "r")
        } label:  {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.down.square")
                .renderingMode(.template)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
        }
    }
}




//Third VStack
//Forward left
struct ForwardLeft: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            print("Move foward left")
        } label:  {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.up.right.square")
                .renderingMode(.template)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
        }
    }
}

//Forward
struct Forward: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            mqttClient.publish("robot/move", withString: "f")
            print("Move forward")
        } label:  {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.right.square")
                .renderingMode(.template)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
        }
    }
}

//Forward right
struct ForwardRight: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            print("Move top right")
        } label:  {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.down.right.square")
                .renderingMode(.template)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure what is wrong, because when l press connect the message shows up on the PI terminal but when l press a direction button nothing shows up. I am thinking it might be a connection issue or something l did wrong in the IOS code. Thanks in advance

I tried to change the swiftUI code but it didn't work

Comment: Not all of your buttons are wired to publish. You’re calling connect on the iOS side but not checking for status of the connection. I’d start debugging there to make sure a connection is established.

Comment: Ok after a couple of debugging, l got it fixed. I checked the connection using the command 'sudo cat /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log' and it was established but it still wouldn't publish any messages. Not sure what the problem was, but l reinstalled mosquitto and that seemed to make the issue go away. Thanks!